# Prediction of collision place and time in Unity

Tags: unity, collision-prediction

I have two moving objects. I have chosen trajectories for objects that they would definitely collide if they don't change speed or trajectory. Is there easy way to check at which point and time the objects will collide with given parameters (current object positions, their velocity vectors and speeds or any other parameter accessible from Unity)?

Comment: Check out this question and answer, I think it covers what you're asking; http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115076/predicting-enemy-movement

Comment: Question linked by bornander is how to determine an intercept, but the same math will also tell you the *time* at which the intercept occurs.  It won't be hard to reengineer the formula to give you the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to just simulate forward in time until the collision happens. Take copies of all the relevant datum (positions, velocities) and loop, incrementing everything until you detect the collision.

To figure out when it will happen, take the game time before you do the above and each time you loop, add X to it, where X is the average frame time that you've been calculating in anticipation for this moment. Hopefully that will give you a decently accurate answer.

Note: I've not used Unity very much, hence the distinct lack of a helpful code sample in my answer, but hopefully this will help a little. It's how I would first try doing it, at any rate.

Comment: Well it was my first intention to do that, but I've done it with progression, checked positions at first, second, fourth and eighth seconds, and with this scenario if collision is on fifth second I will not know, and to check every second would be to heavy solution for my case

Comment: Maybe this will help if your objects are moving at constant velocities? It sounds like the same problem, or at least a spin on it. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115076/predicting-enemy-movement?lq=1